# How to show file path in <input type="file" />?

Tags: html, file, input

I tried `<input type="file" value="path..." />` but not working.

How to fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file input cannot be prepopulated by the webpage.

This is to avoid situations such as:

```
<input
  type="file"
  value="path-to-standard-location-for-quicken-data-files"
  style="display: none">
```

Comment: Can you just tell me Why Or provide the specs?

Comment: sorry for wrong suggestion i remember it next time ok dorward

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that for security reasons this is not possible. The browser will dictate how the file input field will be handled and only the user can change the value by clicking on the Browse button.

From the W3C specification:

> input type="file":
>        Creates a file select control. User agents may use the value of the
>   value attribute as the initial file
>   name.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't know anything about the file structure on the users end, you cannot predefine the file to pick. And it would be pretty insecure when you could just make the `<input />` hidden and send it with a form...